# Не работает сохранение времени через behavior в open server

Tags: yii2

Всем привет есть задача сделать автозаполнение времени через behavior но с ним данные не сохраняются в Бд, может кто помочь разобраться в чем дело?

```css
<?php

use yii\db\Migration;

/**
 * Class m190727_130600_authors
 */
class m190727_130600_authors extends Migration
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function safeUp()
    {
        $this->createTable('{{%authors}}', [
            'id' => $this->primaryKey(),
            'name' => $this->string(255)->notNull(),
            'patronymic' => $this->string(255),
            'surname' => $this->string(255),
            'created_at' => $this->timestamp()->notNull(),
            'updated_at' => $this->timestamp()->notNull(),
        ]);

        $this->alterColumn('authors', 'id', $this->smallInteger(8) . ' NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function safeDown()
    {
        $this->dropTable('{{%authors}}');
    }
}
```

```html
<?php

namespace frontend\models;

use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "authors".
 *
 * @property int $id
 * @property string $name
 * @property string $patronymic
 * @property string $surname
 * @property string $created_at
 * @property string $updated_at
 *
 * @property Books[] $books
 */
class Author extends ActiveRecord
{

    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'authors';
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['name', 'created_at', 'updated_at'], 'required'],
            [['created_at', 'updated_at'], 'safe'],
            [['name', 'patronymic', 'surname'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
        ];
    }

    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'name' => 'Name',
            'patronymic' => 'Patronymic',
            'surname' => 'Surname',
            'created_at' => 'Created At',
            'updated_at' => 'Updated At',
        ];
    }

    public function getBooks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Books::className(), ['id_author' => 'id']);
    }

    /*public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            [
                'class' => TimestampBehavior::className(),
                'attributes' => [
                    ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => ['created_at', 'updated_at'],
                    ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE => ['updated_at'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте изменить тип поля в миграции на integer

```php
           'created_at' => $this->integer(),
           'updated_at' => $this->integer(),
```